# how to access activity log of facebook using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I logged in the facebook account through selenium and is on the home page. How can I go to activity log page using selenium ? As there is not direct id, it is difficult to get there.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
email_field.send_keys("email")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
password_field.send_keys("password")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`find_element_by_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) method of the driver.

In addition to the code you already have, add this

```
logout_menu = driver.find_element_by_id('logoutMenu')
logout_menu.click()
log = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Activity Log')
log.click()
```

This might not always work because the logout menu sometimes takes a little while to load, but you can either add an implicit wait to the driver, or use ExpectedConditions to determine when the Activity Log element is visible and clickable.